# What caused my RAID 5 array to become corrupt?

Tags: raid, raid-5

My machine has an Intel ICH9R RAID controller built in to the motherboard and an additional SIL3124 controller. I had two 1Tb hard disks in a RAID0 array on the Intel controller and 3 1Tb disks in a RAID5 array on the SI controller. Both of these arrays were setup on the controllers themselves (fakeraid) not in Windows.

This box was running Windows 7 just fine until one day it failed to boot. The RAID0 array still looked ok so I installed XP on a different disk and backed up my files from the RAID0 array. I then un-RAIDed the RAID0 array and ran some checks on the disks, one of them had some SMART errors which I hear can cause the array to be marked as broken and become un-bootable.

I've got the data that I need off the RAID0 array but the problem is that I also can't access the RAID5 array. The array looks fine when I boot up and in device manager it has an entry under the hardrives section called 'SiImage SCSI Disk Device' (It isn't meant to be SCSI tho - it's SATA.)

This seems to show that windows can see the controller correctly but if I go to the Volumes tab then it is empty. What could cause this? I'm hoping that it is either the driver that is wrong or something to do with the fact that it was set up under 7 but is now under XP?

I've downloaded SI's RAID tool and it shows the array correctly as "Legacy RG 0".

I can't see the array in Storage Manager.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can use the edit link under your answer to add details.